# python np array change element value in for loop

Tags: python, arrays, copy

I have a question about the element value change in np 2D-array. Here I have a example:

```
a=np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
for i in a: # go through the rows of array
    i=np.array([0,0,0,0,0])

print a
```

The return value is

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
      [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

which means there is no change to the original array. Does it mean the i in the for loop is a copy of each row of array a? If i is the copy, then it makes sense because the change of a copy will not affect the original value. But I try the following code:

```
a=np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
for i in a: # go through the rows of array
    i[:]=np.array([0,0,0,0,0])

print a
```

The return result is

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

so I don'y understand why i[:] can work here if the i is the copy. If this question is duplicated, could you please provide the link?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is not a copy. Keep in mind that `for` loops make repetitive assignments from the items in the iterable to the target list (on the left side of `in`). So at each iteration, `i` holds a reference to each *subarray* in `a`.

Here:

```
for i in a: 
    i = np.array([0,0,0,0,0])
```

You assign each subarray in `a` to the name `i` and immediately afterwards assign the name to an entirely unrelated object. Try `i = 'unrelated'` in that loop, and notice that has no effect (I mean on `a`) other than assign `i` to a new string object.

The second case assigns the subarrays in `a` to `i` in succession (like the first case) but afterwards performs an *in place* modification via the reference `i`.
More clearly, the first iteration of the second case is same as:

```
i = a[0]
i[:] = np.array([0,0,0,0,0])
```

And the second iteration:

```
i = a[1]
i[:] = np.array([0,0,0,0,0])
```

Notice also how in the transition from the first to second iteration `i = a[1]` does not modify the previous reference `a[0]` but instead reassigns the name `i` to a new object `a[1]`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, What is the meaning of _in place_ modification? I agree i holds the reference to the element of a, which means i and a have the same memory address. If I assign `i = np.array([0,0,0,0,0])` in for loop, which means that the i and  np.array([0,0,0,0,0]) have the same memory address and then i and a don't have the same memory address. So the modification of i will not affect a. Is that right?

Comment: Just as you'll do `a[x] = 1` to change the value at an index `x`, you can equally mutate the entire list (in place meaning same object) by using a slice that covers the list `a[:] = [...]`. Yes, I'll say right